# Performing two CompletableFuture Queries one after another without nesting

Tags: java

I have two queries that I'm trying to fetch from a DB. I want to perform A and waiting for it to completely finish and then perform B. I don't need to results from A.

Currently I have gotten them to run one after another by nesting the second query after the first. Is there a way to do it without nesting them?

```
mainRepository.getAppointments().thenAccept(retrievedAppointments -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        //Update ui for query A   
    });
            
    mainRepository.getCustomers().thenAccept(customers -> {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
        //Update ui for query B  
    });
});


public CompletableFuture<ObservableList<Appointment>> getAppointments(){
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            return queryAppointments();
        });
    }

    public CompletableFuture<ObservableList<Customer>> getCustomers(){
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
           return queryCustomers();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does Platform.runLater() return anything?

Comment: no only a update on the ui

Comment: So you need retrievedAppointments  for query A and customers for query B?

Comment: i am using ```retrievedAppointments``` and ```customers``` to update the ui only. I don't need ```retrievedAppointments``` to perform the second query. if that's what you are asking

Comment: You need the retrievedAppointments for the first UI update though right? And you want the second UI update to happen after the first?

Comment: Yes The ui update can happen first or after the second query, doesn't matter. But the second query need to happen after the first finish getting the data.

Comment: Ok last question. Why do you not want them to be nested? What are you trying to avoid? Code cleanliness?

Comment: if i have to perform alot of queries they are all going to be nested. so trying to make it cleaner. i am trying to figure out if it's possible or not. in nodejs you can use ```.then()``` but I couldn't figureout how to do it with java completeablefuture

Comment: I think it should be a similar way in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of method available in the CompletableFuture class similar to what you're expecting from nodeJs `then`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

I don't know your exact use case but one approach you could take is to change the `thenApply` or `thenRun`. This may not be the cleanest solution because I am not 100% familiar with your use case.

```
mainRepository.getAppointments().thenAccept(retrievedAppointments -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                // update ui for query A
            });
        }).thenRun(() -> {
            mainRepository.getCustomers().thenAccept(customers -> {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    //Update ui for query B
                });
        }).thenRun(() -> {
            // do something else
            });
```